# Load when the browser is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, toolbar, add-on

I made a special button that thru the use of this js shows the server status using a api, my problem is that i cant make this thing to automaticly load the first time you open the browser, you have to actually click the button otherwise it doesnt start runing.

```
function checkStatus(event)
{
    jQuery.getJSON("url",function(data){ 
        var button = document.getElementById("ServStat");
        if ( data.status == '1') { 
            jQuery('#ServStat').addClass('online').removeClass('offline');
            button.label = 'Online'; }
        else { 
            jQuery('#ServStat').addClass('offline').removeClass('online');
            button.label = 'Offline' 
        }
    });
}
```

Any ideas are welcome and thanks in advance.

Comment: Is event being used for anything at all? Why are you mixing jQuery and getElementById?

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the interest, indeed "event" and "getElementById" were absolutly uneccessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the code to document.ready function. It gets executed when the document has been load completely.

So your code will become something like,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.getJSON("url", function (data) {
        var button = document.getElementById("ServStat");
        if (data.status == '1') {
            jQuery('#ServStat').addClass('online').removeClass('offline');
            button.label = 'Online';
        } else {
            jQuery('#ServStat').addClass('offline').removeClass('online');
            button.label = 'Offline'
        }
    });
});
```

You can get more details here : http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: a friend also suggested this when i told him the issue, unfortunately and i dont know why but this is not working either. Thanks for the idea and the interest

Comment: When it comes to Jquery, this is the way to do :), you are probably making some syntax error or something else. Make sure that you are not putting in the code within button click event.

Comment: well the problem there is that we need the event in the button aswell as we need it to load as the browser opens, see we need the event to run one time when the browser starts and after that the user has to be able to check it at whenever they want to using the button. :/

Comment: So make another function like checkStatus, move all your code there and call it from both button click and document.ready. :)

Comment: problem is solved, wanted to let you know that your idea also works. If i could vote i would upvote you, many thanks for the interest

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
  checkStatus();
});
```

Comment: also not working, this was the first thing we tried. Thanks for the idea and the interest.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, i really appreaciate you took the time and effort to answer my question, im "new" to the site and let me tell that after this first impression im here for the long term :).

About the issue, well as most of you have noticed im learning from the practice and i dont really have a deep understanding, i try to pay as much attention as i can and read everything that i find, anyway, my friend who does have a deep understanding of this noticed that in my xul file the script were set like this:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://neverendlessbar/content/serverstatus.js" />
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://neverendlessbar/content/jquery-1.7.2.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
</script>
```

When the right way was:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://neverendlessbar/content/jquery-1.7.2.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
</script>
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://neverendlessbar/content/serverstatus.js" />
```

The jQuery wasnt loding properly. After we fixed the jQuery error we just added a simply "checkStatus();" to the end of code leving us with this:

```
function checkStatus(event)
{
    jQuery.getJSON("url",function(data){ 
    var button = document.getElementById("ServStat");
    if ( data.status == '1') { 
    jQuery('#ServStat').addClass('online').removeClass('offline').attr('label','Online');}
    else { 
    jQuery('#ServStat').addClass('offline').removeClass('online').attr('label','Offline');}});
}
checkStatus();
```

Worked in the first run :D.

So thanks again everybody and i hope i can return the favour some day :D.

> After reading epascarello reply i asked and indeed "getElementById" aint neccessary.

FINAL CODE

```
function checkStatus()
{
    jQuery.getJSON("url",function(data){ 
    if ( data.status == '1')     {jQuery('#ServStat').addClass('online').removeClass('offline').attr('label','Online');}
    else     {jQuery('#ServStat').addClass('offline').removeClass('online').attr('label','Offline');}});
}
checkStatus();
{
    setInterval(changeState, 300000)
}
```