# How to extract partial JSON from API response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

[Load when the browser is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220190/load-when-the-browser-is-open)

Thats my previous question related to this topic.

My problem is that the server api i use has added a new item to the list and as i stated in the previous question im not very skilled with API's or jQuery, therefore i would like to know what can you recomend me to read about this and also pratical solutions. I need to make it so the field that the js uses is only {"name":"Arthas","slug":"arthas","build":"12340","status":1} and not the rest.

Many thanks in advance.

This is the api -> http://api.neverendless-wow.com/server-status

```
{"servers":[{"name":"Arthas","slug":"arthas","build":"12340","status":1},{"name":"Deathwing","slug":"deathwing","build":"13623","status":1}],"alerts":[]}
```

This is my current js

```
function checkStatus()
{
    jQuery.getJSON("http://api.neverendless-wow.com/server-status",function(data){ 
    if (data.status == '1')     {jQuery('#ServStat').addClass('online').removeClass('offline').attr('label','Online');}
    else     {jQuery('#ServStat').addClass('offline').removeClass('online').attr('label','Offline');}});
}
checkStatus();
{
    setInterval(changeState, 300000)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use data as array (data[0]) and hence your code will be as follows:

```
function checkStatus()
{
    jQuery.getJSON("http://api.neverendless-wow.com/server-status",function(data){ 
        if (data.servers[0].status == '1') { 
            jQuery('#ServStat').addClass('online').removeClass('offline').attr('label','Online');
        }
        else {
            jQuery('#ServStat').addClass('offline').removeClass('online').attr('label','Offline');
        }
    });
}

checkStatus();
{
    setInterval(changeState, 300000)
}
```

Comment: Try data.servers[0].status instead of data[0].status.

Comment: it worked! thanks alot @Shant , i guess if i want to use the second part {"name":"Deathwing","slug":"deathwing","build":"13623","status":1} instead of data.servers[0].status i will have to use data.servers[1].status

Comment: I have corrected the code snippet in my answer and glad to hear that your issue is resolved. Can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go with something like this:

```
// check server status
function checkStatus()
{
    $.getJSON(server_url, function(data) { 

      // reset
      var mode = "Offline";
      $('.status').removeClass('online').addClass('offline');

      // is available?
      if (data !== null && data.servers !== null && data.servers[0].status === 1) {
        mode = "Online";        
        $('.status').removeClass('offline').addClass('online');
      }

      // Extract data from received JSON string is exists
      extractData(data);

      // set needed attributes
      $('.status')
        .attr('label', mode)
        .text('Servers are ' + mode);
    });
}
```

Live demo [available on JsBin](http://jsbin.com/uqevac/2/edit)